# Creating labels for data based on first 3 characters in cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with ID numbers, and the first three characters indicate a label of interest I want to create in a separate column.

The first three characters of ID and labels are as follows:
182: turtles, 187: rabbits, 196: cats, and all the rest are "None". An example output which I did manually looks like this:

[image: example output]

I'm a novice at excel, and attempted a formula which was something like this but couldn't figure out how to finish it or make it work:

[image: a feeble attempt]

The actual data is too much to actually do manually. I'm open to whatever approach works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: Using `XLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=XLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3)+0,{182,187,196},{"Turtles","Rabbits","Cats"},"None")
```

---

Or, You can `#SPILL!` as an array.

```
=XLOOKUP(LEFT(A2:A15,3)+0,{182,187,196},{"Turtles","Rabbits","Cats"},"None")
```

---

**Few other alternatives:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IFERROR(IFS(LEFT(A2,3)+0=182,"Turtles",LEFT(A2,3)+0=187,"Rabbits",LEFT(A2,3)+0=196,"Cats"),"None")
```

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=SWITCH(LEFT(A2,3)+0,182,"Turtles",187,"Rabbits",196,"Cats","None")
```

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUM(N(--LEFT(A2,3)={182,187,196})*{1,2,3}),"Turtles","Rabbits","Cats"),"None")
```

---